# Merging arrays for json output

Tags: php, json

I been looking around and came across `array_merge()` and `json_decode()`.

I have code were it looks through a file and loops through each line that then pushes that data into a search to pull back information (the information returns as json output.)

File contents:

```
spotify:track:2SZy40PLDk3vFucXUGFCFA
spotify:track:1ZQnV7ePl8yXoLjPfhWE5L
spotify:track:4NbvIwYcwx8dNGYfUX2bKB
```

Echoed Output:

```
{"type":"track","artist":"Jax Jones, Raye","title":"You Don't Know Me","album":"You Don't Know Me","duration":214000,"offset":0,"available":true,"popularity":88} {"type":"track","artist":"MK, Becky Hill","title":"Piece of Me","album":"Piece of Me","duration":189000,"offset":0,"available":true,"popularity":65} {"type":"track","artist":"Wankelmut, Emma Louise","title":"My Head Is A Jungle - MK Remix / Radio Edit","album":"My Head Is A Jungle (MK Remix / Radio Edit)","duration":205000,"offset":0,"available":true,"popularity":62}
```

I want to merge all that data into one json thats called tracks, something like `{"tracks":[{"` and inside have the json information.

My Code:

```
$contents = '';
$dataarray = file('/location/'.$_GET['playlist'].''); //Push file data into array
$finallist = '';

//Grab Track Info

//echo count($dataarray);
foreach ($dataarray as $line_num => $line) //Loop Through Data
{
    $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line); //Replace new line on string

    $contents = searchCommand($connect, 'uinfo '.$line); //Returns Json for that single track
    if (stripos($contents, '"error":"invalid argument (should be a Spotify URI)"') == FALSE && stripos($contents, '"error": "invalid command"') == FALSE) //If we found tracks
    {
        echo $contents;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Fail";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an array and converted it to json and so i can read it via `JS`.

```
foreach ($dataarray as $line_num => $line) //Loop Through Data
{
    $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line); //Replace new line on string

    $contents = searchSpopCommand($spop, 'uinfo '.$line); //Returns Json for that single track
    if (stripos($contents, '"error":"invalid argument (should be a Spotify URI)"') == FALSE && stripos($contents, '"error": "invalid command"') == FALSE) //If we found tracks
    {
        $finallist .= $contents;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Fail";
    }
}
$array = explode("\n", $finallist);
array_pop($array);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Would of been ideal if i can give it a name though!